# Программа не закрывается полностью

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Есть следующий код:
[image]

Содержимое XML файла:
[image]

он находится на событии закрытия формы. При закрытии формы она скрывается, но процесс программы остаётся. Visual Studio никаких ошибок не выводит.

Comment: Вы поток оставляете открытым. Закройте все потоки программы, и все будет ок

Comment: Код в вопросе должен быть текстом, а не картинкой.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для выхода из приложения попробуйте следующий код:

```
Application.ExitThread();
Environment.Exit(0);
```

Ссылки:

- Источник: [Application is still running in memory after Application.Exit() is called](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25050689/5275890)
- [`Application.ExitThread`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.forms.application.exitthread(v=vs.110).aspx)
- [`Environment.Exit`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.environment.exit(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Process.GetCurrentProcess().Kill(); или System.Environment.Exit(0); попробуйте